# MediaCodecList for Google TV/Honeycomb

Tags: google-tv

Is there an equivalent to the MediaCodecList that will work on Honeycomb/Google TV.  Basically I need to be able to get a list of supported video/audio codecs that a particular device supports.  This will then be used to determine whether I need to go transcode the file on the server and stream via HTTPS Live streaming, or if I can just send the file directly to the video player with out transcoding.  I know that each device can support a different number of codecs and types, so something like MediaCodecList would seem to be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official list is at https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_media_formats - I don't think https is supported for HLS.

Comment: Sorry ment HLS not HTTPs.  Saw that list, but can't manufactures add additional formats?  I guess I can wrap this with a try catch and if something fails to play, know at that point I have to fall back to the HLS and Transcoding option.  Thanks Les.

Comment: Yes - manufactures can and do add additional codecs.  No easy dynamic way to figure it out.  Though, once you figure it out for an individual box, you can save that info. Starting with the latest build to LG, others coming soon - you can write a codec or transport in Java.  If you need this, let me now at my google email or g+ address.

Comment: What would be really nice is something like [MediaCodeList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecList.html).  But that is only available in API Level 16, it looks like it relies on some native code libraries to be available in order to work, so not sure if it can be backported to API Level 13 or not.  I should be starting work next week on the playback and if I run into issues, I'll post a message to this site.  Thanks.